# sorting a map based on value

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose I have a `std::map<std::string,int>` this map stores an id along with a debt amount.
I want to know if there was a way for me to obtain the 5 highest (int) values from the map.
I know I could iterate through the map and do a custom sort however is there a custom algorithm that might help me accomplish this ? What would the most efficient way be ?

Comment: You can use bidirectional map from boost instead of `std::map`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you save them in another place while inserting to the map and maintain it. 
A map is just a map....
Getting the highest 5 will be o(N) on the map. if you manage them while inserting you can do it in o(1)

Answer (score 0):

Create a map `std::map<int, std::string>` and insert all data from old map into this map.
Then 5 key from end of new map have the highest value.

Comment: This is similar to iterating over the map... :-)

Comment: @Dani Except it is not robust against duplicate values.

Comment: @juanchopanza : It's true, only the last duplicate value is inserted.

Comment: @Dani: In terms of complexity you are right.   
My method is o(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

you could build a vector of iterators into the map:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // make some data
    using data_map_type = map<string, int>;
    data_map_type data_map = {
        { "a", 10 },
        { "b", 5 },
        { "c", 3 },
        { "d", 3 },
        { "e", 4 },
        { "f", 1 },
        { "g", 2 },
        { "h", 5 },
        { "i", 0 },
        { "j", 2 },
        { "k", 1 },
    };

    // build reverse index (initially unordered)
    std::vector<data_map_type::const_iterator> second_index;
    for(auto it = begin(data_map) ; it != end(data_map) ; ++it)
        second_index.push_back(it);

    // order the secondary index by descending debt amount
    sort(begin(second_index),
         end(second_index),
         [](const data_map_type::const_iterator& l,
            const data_map_type::const_iterator& r)
         {
             return l->second > r->second;
         });

    // emit the top 5 (or fewer)
    const auto limit = std::min(second_index.size(), size_t(5));
    cout << "top " << limit << " entries:" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < limit ; ++i)
    {
        cout << "key=" << second_index[i]->first << ", value=" << second_index[i]->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```